# typo3 php file in public folder access controller function

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

is there any posibillity to access a controller function from a php file that is based in resource/public/php/file.php

What I want is this php file is special file I use it for this:

```
<img src="file.php"></img>
```

I will disable readable paths. So this php file does some encryption and need a connection to a normal controller function.

thanks

Comment: Hey did my answer help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any posibillity to access a controller function from a php file that is based in resource/public/php/file.php

Yes, it is possible but therefor you need to `bootstrap` the TYPO3 core as well. Or if it is a `static` and `public` method than you can call it directly.

But this seems not the right way to do it in your case.

Assuming you're working on some kind of captcha thing you should consider your own `page type` for rendering the `dynamic images`. Here's a working example:

**TypoScript Setup**

In TypoScript we're registering our own `page typ` and pointing it out to our `extension`, `controller` and `action`:

```
DynamicCaptchaImage = PAGE
DynamicCaptchaImage {

    typeNum = 1234

    10 = USER_INT
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        pluginName = Pi1
        extensionName = MyExtName
        vendorName = MyCompanyName
        controller = MyExtbaseController
        action = renderCaptchaImage
        # view =< plugin.tx_myextname.view  // you provide the view yourself
        # persistence =< plugin.tx_myextname.persistence // in case you need a repository you should uncomment it
        settings =< plugin.tx_myextname.settings
    }

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-Type: image/png
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
    }
}
```

See also: [Registering a custom typeNum-based Controller access](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/wildside_extbase/ExtWildsideExtbaseFramework/Bits-and-piecesDetailedExampleAnAjaxCalendar/RegisteringACustomTypenum-basedControllerAccess/Index.html)

**Controller**

Here's an example how your `controller` and `action` should look like:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompanyName\MyExtName\Controller;

/**
 * MyExtbaseController
 */
class MyExtbaseController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * Render Captcha Image Action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function renderCaptchaImageAction() {

        // Send some headers
        header('Content-Type: image/png');

        // < do your magic stuff here >

        // Breaks the script because we've sent already some headers and want
        // to prevent that TYPO3 is adding another stuff (eg. for debugging purposes)
        // that can break the image from loading.
        // return FALSE; does not stop doing that!
        exit;
    }

}
```

See also: [Extbase wiki](https://wiki.typo3.org/Extbase)

**Accessing the controller**

Now we've configured the custom `page type` we're allowed to access the controller by calling the `page type` given in the TypoScript setup.

Eg. http://www.example.com?type=1234 points out to the `renderCaptchaImageAction()` in the `MyExtbaseController`.

**Fluid**

In Fluid you can link to the `page type` you've configured by:

```
<img src="{f:link.page(pageType: 1234)}" />
```

See also: [Fluid wiki](https://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f:link.page)

**Realurl**

If you're using the extension `realurl` you can change `?type=1234` to `captcha.png` by:

```
// [...]
'fileName' => array(
    'index' => array(
        'captcha.png' => array(
            'keyValues' => array(
                'type' => 1234,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
// [...]
```

See also: [Realurl wiki](https://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual#-.3EfileName)